# baking material only turns out black from high poly to low poly model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I'm trying to bake the material from the high poly scan of a person to the low poly made in instant meshes.
I'm using a diffuse BSDF I only want the colour info to see that it can be done.

I have corrected the sharp angles and shaded to smooth.  i have smart uv unwrapped the low poly.

I have checked the normals and then changed the ray extrusion when baking.
All transforms are 0. i have smart uv unwrapped the low poly.
I have tried baking with a cage, baking with the low poly bigger than the high poly.

All end up in a straight white or black bake. All the tutorials i have seen don't bother with light before because I only want the color data?

Baking detail does work from a simple plane to another plane, so I have that going for me.

Blend file should be attached

[image]